# Tab in Input cell

Tags: keyboard, cells, comment, input

Why is it impossible to use tab to indent e.g. an inline comment i.e. (* ... *) in an Input cell?

However, I have seen that it is possible, if I use Cell>ConvertTo>TextDisplay. The cell remains evaluatable, but the cell bracket goe wwithout the diagonal decoration at the upper end.

Answer (score 1):

In Input cells <kbd>Tab</kbd> has another use: to move between [`Placeholder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placeholder.html) characters and other "active" objects.

You can still use other ways to insert a `\[RawTab]` character such as an Input Alias.  To create one in the current Notebook evaluate:

```
AppendTo[
  CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], InputAliases],
  "ta" -> "\t"
]
```

You can then enter a raw tab with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`ta`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.  If you like this you can make it a persisting change by replacing `InputNotebook[]` with `$FrontEnd` and evaluating it again, but only do it once.  Or use the Option Inspector to edit the **Global** value for **InputAliases**.

Comment: I like to use Code cells (Alt 8): there tab behaves nice.

Comment: @RolfMertig Szabolcs had an answer where he suggested that but he deleted it.  (You can't *quite* see "deleted" posts yet.)  As noted in the comments Tab only works at the beginning of lines there whereas the OP wants tabs mid-line.